# Uncaught Reference Error : process is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, mern, uncaught-reference-error

I am getting process is not defined error while running the react app.

**I'm getting this error whenever I do the following steps :**

1. Run npm run start (react-scripts start)
2. Edit the code and save it
3. The error message is displayed on the browser's console and the application is frozen.

[image]

Comment: `process` doesn't exist in the browser

Comment: ok so how can we fix the error

Comment: Don’t use `process` in front-end code, or code meant for the browser.